# ionic 4 Video Player Plugin/Streaming Media Plugin not working in android 9

Tags: android, angular7, ionic4, ionic-native

I am trying to use Video Player Plugin/Streaming Media Plugin of ionic4 to play video in my app but this plugins are working in android 6 & android 8 but not working in android 9, I try to use this only plugin with ionic 4 default app but that build of android 9 also doesn't play video

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I changed the `defaultTargetSdkVersion` and it worked for me.